# Digital Persona Finger Print 4500 integration ASP.NET and C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, hardware

I want to integrate Digital Persona Finger Print 4500 model with my ASP.NET application. I want to register an employee thumb and save it in a SQL Server database, then in next screen just want to verify it using thumb.

If someone has done this already in ASP.NET with C# and SQL Server, please guide me.

Thanks & regards

Comment: What kind of integration are you looking for? Do you need a front-end/browser integration or server-side validation of an existing image?

Comment: I want to make two screen,  1st Employee Registration, and 2nd Employee Verification, In First screen it will ask Employee Id, Name and Thumb Registration and then save it into SQL database, 2nd screen will just verify the thumb and get info from database. This should be developed in ASP.Net with C#